# Does every windows comes with user32.dll?

Tags: c#, windows, dll, dllimport

I have c# application that contains the code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]  
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

to get current window title . Now I have to deploy the application , I want to know that does every type of windows (64 and 32bit and XP,7,vista,8,10)comes with user32.dll or I have to make users download that first?

Comment: Long story short - yes.

Comment: IIRC it was named `user.exe` in Win16, but it did exist.

Comment: If they did have to, where would they download it?

Comment: MSDN has dedicate articles on each Win32 API and on which Windows versions they are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be sure that user32.dll will always be present, as it is part of the [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

I could imagine a world where Microsoft comes up with win 11/12/etc.. And they are so frustrated with having to keep up with their old API that they throw user32.dll out the window(s).

Like with any API break - deal with it when it present's itself. if you plan for every eventuality - you will have to wait it out and never publish a single bit of software.

Answer (score 0):

It is a core dll like kernel32.dll. It contains all necesary API that a windows user can call. So yes, it is present in any windows version

Answer (score 0):

Yes it comes by default with every window,

> USER32.DLL implements the Windows USER component that creates and
>   manipulates the standard elements of the Windows user interface, such
>   as the desktop, windows, and menus. It thus enables programs to
>   implement a graphical user interface (GUI) that matches the Windows
>   look and feel. Programs call functions from Windows USER to perform
>   operations such as creating and managing windows, receiving window
>   messages (which are mostly user input such as mouse and keyboard
>   events, but also notifications from the operating system), displaying
>   text in a window, and displaying message boxes.
>
> Many of the functions in USER32.DLL call upon GDI functions exported
>   by GDI32.DLL to do the actual rendering of the various elements of the
>   user interface. Some types of programs will also call GDI functions
>   directly to perform lower-level drawing operations within a window
>   previously created via USER32 functions.

Source [Wiki User32.dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#USER32.DLL)